# How to find a dynamically added array element in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, google-chrome-extension

So basically I'm adding an element to an array and then creating a block of text for that element. The problem is I keep getting undefined as the result of calling that element in a function I created to set the block text to the dynamically added element text. When I click on the block it goes through a `$(document).on(click)` function and so all of the data in the arrays shows up.

The save function:

```
function saveNote() {
    var noteTitle = document.getElementById("note-title");
    var noteText = document.getElementById("note-text");

    var noteTitleContent = noteTitle.value;
    var noteTextContent = noteText.value;

    /* SAVING NOTE HEADER & TEXT IN DOUBLE ARRAY */
    chrome.storage.local.get('noteTitleList', function (x) {
        var titleSet = x.noteTitleList;
        titleSet.push(noteTitleContent);

        chrome.storage.local.set({noteTitleList: titleSet}, function() {
            console.log('titleSet Saved: ' + titleSet);
        });
    });

    chrome.storage.local.get('noteTextList', function (x) {
        var textSet = x.noteTextList;
        textSet.push(noteTextContent);

        chrome.storage.local.set({noteTextList: textSet}, function() {
            console.log('textSet Saved: ' + textSet);
        });
    });

    addNote();
}
```

The addNote function:

```
function addNote() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('noteTitleList', function (x) {
        var titleSet = x.noteTitleList;
        var titleSetLength = titleSet.length;
        var noteTitle = titleSet[titleSetLength]; // results in an undefined

        $element = document.createElement("section");
        $($element).addClass('note-' + titleSetLength);
        $($element).addClass('notelink');
        $element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(noteTitle)); // section text says undefined
        document.getElementById('saved-note-area').appendChild($element);
        $delete = document.createElement("i");
        $($delete).addClass('fa');
        $($delete).addClass('fa-trash-o');
        $($delete).addClass('trash-' + titleSetLength);
        document.getElementById('saved-note-area').appendChild($delete);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is way too much code. consider stripping out irrelevant stuff.

Comment: It looks to me like you are overlooking that the `chrome.local.storage` functions are asynchronous.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with updating the DOM... I just don't know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your code to work with four changes:

---

(1) The biggest change was to rewrite the `saveNote()` function so it does not call `addNote()` until the `chrome.storage.local.set` function's callback is called. This change is needed because the `chrome.local.storage` functions are asynchronous.

```
function saveNote() {
    var noteTitleContent = document.getElementById("note-title").value;
    var noteTextContent = document.getElementById("note-text").value;

    /* SAVING NOTE HEADER & TEXT IN DOUBLE ARRAY */
    chrome.storage.local.get(['noteTitleList', 'noteTextList'], function (x) {
        var titleSet = x.noteTitleList || [];
        var textSet = x.noteTextList || [];

        titleSet.push(noteTitleContent);
        textSet.push(noteTextContent);

        chrome.storage.local.set({noteTitleList: titleSet, noteTextList: textSet}, function() {
            addNote();
        });
    });
}
```

Notice how you can store values to both arrays in one call to `chrome.storage.local.set`.

---

(2) There is a syntax error for the closing of the `addNote()` function. Change `});` to just `}`.

---

(3) In the `addNote()` function, subtract one from the array length to get the last item. Change to:

```
var noteTitle = titleSet[titleSetLength-1];
```

---

(4) In the click handler for the note link (which you removed from the question), add `1` to `c` when putting together the class name. This is needed because the loop index `c` is zero-based, while the numbers on the class names are one-based.

```
if($this.hasClass('note-'+(c+1))) {
```

That line occurs in two places.

---

You should also place all the code in a document-ready handler. (At least the code that registers the event handlers should go in there.)

---

There are other improvements I would recommend, but this answer is already quite long. The biggest would be to get rid of the for-loops in the click-handler for the note links.

Comment: @Nesiehr - I added a new answer. I had never create a chrome extension before, but I just put one together with your code. After making the changes listed in this answer, it worked for me.